# Jensen's gap between $| \int f \,d \mu | ^2 $ and $ \int |f|^2,d \mu$ especially when $\mu = \mathbb{P}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality, integral-inequality

Do we have tools by which we can measure
$$ 
\int |f|^2 \,d \mu - \left| \int f \,d \mu \right| ^2
$$ especially when $\mu = \mathbb{P}$?

I am especially interested in the cases when $f$ is such simple that $f(x) = x + c$ with some constant $c$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and with an integral domain $(a, \infty)$:

$$
\int_a^\infty (x+c)^2p(x)\,dx - \left|\int_a^\infty (x+c)p(x)\,dx \right|^2
$$

Comment: What you are asking is exactly the variance $$ \operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}X)^2 = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega)^2 \, \mathbb{P}(d\omega) - \left( \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) \, \mathbb{P}(d\omega) \right)^2. $$ The situation becomes no simpler even you focus on the case $f(x) = x$, since any distributional information of a random variable can be encoded within $\mathbb{P}$. That being said, your question seems so generic to me as there are infinite freedom of playing with the variance.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but what is $\mu = \mathbb{P}$?

Comment: @MartinR I think he means it's a probability measure